# Download an excel sheet on link button click on spotfire

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-analyst

Whats the better way to download the details in the format of an excel sheet as soon user click on the link button?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use markings to then display the detailed data in a table visual then the user can right click on the table visual to download the data.

Without more context (ie: if the excel sheets are already created and saved somewhere outside of spotfire ect ) this would be the best option.

Comment: Rather user clicking the right click can't it be done on single click. 
Isn't there any way where on click on link button i can pass this as a parameter to one if the datatable to filter and download it as excel file.

Comment: You could pass the marking to document property then use it to filter a table visual. The problem is there is no easy way to export data to an EXCEL document from the webplayer. The option I've used to export data from webplayer to a CSV file is detailed here https://community.tibco.com/questions/data-export-excel-web-player

Comment: You could try this method : https://spotfired.blogspot.com/2014/02/exporting-to-excel-web-player.html and save to a Network drive. {but this feature is to save to the Server so no option to save to user desktop}